# How to make autoscale ignore non-visible (hidden) objects?

Tags: python, matplotlib

How can I make autoscale ignore non-visible plot elements? I would like to be able to choose the scaling a few different times/ways, after turning on/off various plotted elements.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

h1 = plt.plot([0,1],[0,1])
h2 = plt.plot([2,3],[2,3], visible=False)
plt.autoscale(enable=True, axis='y', tight=True)
plt.show()
```

The above does not zoom in on the displayed/visible elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the following before autoscale:

```
plt.gca().relim(visible_only=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

The visibility alone will not change the autoscaling behaviour, since the line is still there, no matter if it is visible or not.

You may remove the line from the axes. `h2.remove()`. Then `relim` the plot, then autoscale.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

h1, = plt.plot([0,1],[0,1])
h2, = plt.plot([2,3],[2,3])
h2.remove()
plt.gca().relim()
plt.autoscale(enable=True, axis='y', tight=True)

plt.show()
```

To later put the line back to the axes use `axes.add_line(h2)`, then `relim` and `autoscale` again.

```
plt.gca().add_line(h2)
plt.gca().relim()
plt.autoscale(enable=True, axis='y', tight=True)
```

Comment: Sorry -- that looks like a great answer which I should have accepted years ago. My attention just came back to this with @Aking's update (maybe a new feature??), which looks even better.